# pyd error install qgis 2.14

Tags: qgis, python, installation

I removed qgis 2.10 so i could install qgis 2.14. But when i try to install 2.14 i get errors on python .pyd packages. Every time it is a different pyd causing the error.
I had this problem with flapack, bestand_controls for example.

If anyone can help me out here?